# Android Login Alternatives

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, registration

I'm implementing various things at the moment, but the one thing that boggles me is **Android Login Mechanism**. I'm not so sure which login mechanism to choose from in different applications (where all of them are accessing internet).

Let's say I have two apps:

- A: This app basically should connect to the server and let users chat - we can see the online user list (no roster, everybody is friend with everybody), so it's a chatting application.
- B. This app should authenticate to the server and let users post messages to their WALL or something, so when the other user comes online it will instantly display those messages to him.

---

I'm deliberately using "connect to the server" trying to be generic, since this is what I want to know. What type of authentication should I use, so that my server knows that the user is legitimate one:

- 1) **Custom Registration + Login:** I don't want to use that, since users don't want to register another username and there are a lot of alternatives available.
- 2) **OpenID:** I should use this when I only need authenticated users, without the need to access their private information on whatever site. I'm not too fond of this, because a browser needs to open for this to work.
- 3) **OAuth**: The same as OpenID, but I can also get access to private resources of the user. Here is the same problem, a browser needs to open exchanging the keys and tokens, so it doesn't make too good user experience.
- 4) **AccountManager**: This is a very good option, but I don't like it, since it's not a part of the application. I'm not even sure what should happen when the user hits the Login button, and AccountManager pops up. Should I choose the existing account alraedy listed in the AccountManager, what if I want to choose a different account, like Yahoo, etc - can AccountManager register it, login to it, and return the application - authenticated.

---

I would very much like to hear the existing implementations of all of the 4 alternatives that I can use. I know there are a lot of them out there and I don't want them listed here, I know them. The only problem is that I don't know which one of them to use, that will do the work the way I want. The following is a list of things I want:

- 1) In the application, when user clicks the Login button, something should open letting the user choose between the following alternatives: Google, Facebook, Yahoo, Twitter. The user should login with whatever account, which should be noted as authenticated.
- 2) That account should then be user as an access token to authenticate to my server - so my server only accepts the token and check that it's valid.

The whole point of this is that I don't have to implement login mechanism on my server, but users are still authenticated against my server, so we can exchange some data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.myapplication;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText login_uname, login_pwd;
        TextView invalid_error;
        Button login_btn;
        private boolean canExit;
        TextView pword_showhide;

        // string login_un,login_pw;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

            login_uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
            login_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
            invalid_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.InvalidError);
            login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            // loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
            invalid_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pword_showhide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd_showhide);
            // pword_showhide.setText("show");
            pword_showhide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (login_pwd.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                        login_pwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        pword_showhide.setText("show");
                    } else {
                        login_pwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                        pword_showhide.setText("hide");
                    }
                    login_pwd.setSelection(login_pwd.getText().length());
                }
            });
            checkValidation();
            login_uname.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
            login_pwd.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
        }
        private void checkValidation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(login_uname.getText())) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(login_pwd.getText())))
                login_btn.setEnabled(false);
            else {
                login_btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        public void login(View view) {
            if (login_uname.getText().toString().equals("a") && login_pwd.getText().toString().equals("a")) {
                invalid_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                login_uname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_username, 0, 0, 0);
                login_pwd.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_password, 0, 0, 0);
                //correcct password
            } else {
                //wrong password
                invalid_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                login_uname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.error_username, 0, 0, 0);
                login_pwd.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.error_password,0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkValidation();
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (canExit)
                super.onBackPressed();
            else {
                canExit = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 2000/*time interval to next press in milli second*/);// if not pressed within 2seconds then will be setted(canExit) as false
        }
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {
                    case 1:
                        canExit = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

    }

login_screen.xml
----------------
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Invalid Login Details"
        android:id="@+id/InvalidError"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff3a0f"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/login_lyt">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_username"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"
            android:layout_marginTop="141dp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="******"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pwd_showhide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="show" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:background="#f0a422"
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    package com.myapplication;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText login_uname, login_pwd;
        TextView invalid_error;
        Button login_btn;
        private boolean canExit;
        TextView pword_showhide;

        // string login_un,login_pw;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

            login_uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
            login_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
            invalid_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.InvalidError);
            login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            // loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
            invalid_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pword_showhide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd_showhide);
            // pword_showhide.setText("show");
            pword_showhide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (login_pwd.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                        login_pwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        pword_showhide.setText("show");
                    } else {
                        login_pwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                        pword_showhide.setText("hide");
                    }
                    login_pwd.setSelection(login_pwd.getText().length());
                }
            });
            checkValidation();
            login_uname.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
            login_pwd.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
        }

        private void checkValidation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(login_uname.getText())) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(login_pwd.getText())))
                login_btn.setEnabled(false);
            else {
                login_btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkValidation();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (canExit)
                super.onBackPressed();
            else {
                canExit = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 2000/*time interval to next press in milli second*/);// if not pressed within 2seconds then will be setted(canExit) as false
        }

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case 1:
                        canExit = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }



 login_screen.xml:
    ------------------
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Invalid Login Details"
            android:id="@+id/InvalidError"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff3a0f"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/login_lyt">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/login_username"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"
                android:layout_marginTop="141dp" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="******"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_password"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pwd_showhide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="show" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:background="#f0a422"
                android:id="@+id/login_btn"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```